# Powershell script Missingtypename

Tags: json, powershell, jenkins, jira, octopus-deploy

I am trying to make some API calls through powershell using this documentation
https://octopus.com/blog/manually-push-build-information-to-octopus

```
        $Headers = @{"X-Octopus-ApiKey"=$MYKEY"}
        $jsonBody = @{
            PackageId = "Test"
            Version = "1.1.1"
            OctopusBuildInformation =
                @{
                    BuildEnvironment = "Jenkins"
                    BuildNumber = "1"
                    BuildURL = "myURL"
                    VcsCommitNumber = "250"
                    VcsType = "Git"

                    Commits = [{Id = "250" LinkUrl = "gitUrl" Comment = "someComment"}]
                    VcsRoot = "gitUrl"
                }
         } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "http://alfadeployment/api/build-information" -Headers $Headers -Body $jsonBody
```

However, since I added the commits array, I am getting the following error:

```
  Missing type name after '['.
      + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell arrays aren't enclosed in `[...]` - the latter is used for *type literals*, i.e. to refer to .NET types - hence the error message.

You *may* - but don't have to - enclose PowerShell arrays in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--); using `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) is enough, though `@(...)` can be helpful for visual clarity, and to create an *empty* (`@()`) or *single-element* arrays (`@('foo')`), which is perhaps clearer than the *unary* use of `,` (`, 'foo'`)).

Additionally, the array *element* in your case must be a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) too (`@{ ... }`, not `{ ... }`, the latter is a *script block*), and, given that the property definitions are on the *same line*, they must be `;`-separated.

To put it all together:

```
Commits = @(
  @{ Id = "250"; LinkUrl = "gitUrl"; Comment = "someComment" }
)
```